# Npm Start Causes sleep is not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, sleep

I cloned a react project from github, I ran **npm install** and the **node_modules** folder eas installed. Then I tried to run **npm start** but it causes

```
'sleep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

Comment: `sleep -- suspend execution for an interval of time` is available on UNIX

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly This is project tested on Mac and Linux, the author said to me it works fine. So what should I do now (I'm using Windows 10)

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: It probably _does_ work fine on macOS and Linux, because they both have *nix command lines where sleep is defined.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the `sleep` UNIX command and is not available on windows. Try to run the command using **Git Bash**. You can find the Git Bash in start menu or context menu if you have installed it along with Git for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I located the file where the sleep command is found and I removed it and the error is gone:
test-builder: **sleep 20** && npm run test-builder --silent
unit: **sleep 40** && npm run unit-minimal --silent

I really need to ask why the **sleep command** is used.

Another errors appears but they're independent. Thank u for the help